# how can i correct this warning error im getting

Tags: php, mysql

How can I correct this error I'm getting in my function, below is my error

```
Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\how are things\15_06_widget_corp-final\includes\functions.php on line 40
Database query failed:
```

the code on line 40 is this

```
$subject_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
```

This is my function code

```
function get_all_subjects($public = true) {
        global $connection;
        $query = "SELECT * 
                FROM subjects ";
        if ($public) {
            $query .= "WHERE visible = 1 ";
        }
        $query .= "ORDER BY position ASC";
        $subject_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
        confirm_query($subject_set);
        return $subject_set;
    }
```

Comment: You should use `mysqli_query()` instead of `mysql_query()`. For your problem, the mysql_connect has certainly failed and the var your are giving to mysql_query is not a valid resource. Check your global `$connection`

Comment: See if this will help shed some light on it > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039561/php-sql-database-query-error-message

Comment: and what is the comfirm_query function?

Comment: Did you read the error message ?? `mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, null given` The problem is the connection resource (the `global $connection`) that is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It requires `$connection` to be reference to connection to mysql server.
Try

```
  $connection = mysql_connect('host','user','pass');
```

Comment: The $connection exists as global var. read before answering dude

Comment: Then your $connection is not valid or close

Comment: Yes that is the problem. That error clearly states that it was null. So somehow that variable is not being carried over as expected. But it's not the solution. Solution would be to first check why that variable is not carrying a value, rather than trying to reconnect to database without knowing.

Answer (score 0):

You must assign `$connection` to a

```
mysql_connect()
```

function

Anyway you should not use mysql functions anymore because they are deprecated.
You can use [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly/) instead.